# Larger video size after exporting from .mov to .mp4

Tags: video-editor, export

I'm working on video editing on VSDC and my exports are so much larger then the original video when I export it into mp4 format.

All I did to the video was delete the sound from the video and replace it with the same sound which I cleaned up a bit with audacity and exported into wav-format.

The original size of the video was 34MB and the wav-file was about 4MB but the export was over 200MB.

I exported it with the option that the software was for YouTube and set the quality for 1080p.

I don't understand what's going on!
Could it be that my original video is of a lesser quality then 1080?

And the software is adding filler pixels?

The original was a mov-file.
Are these the numbers I should be looking at?

[image: Settings]

I got a more reasonable file size of 31MB when I exported to avi.
And exporting to mkv is only 41MB.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to tell us which software you're using. I'm assuming it's the adobe media encoder? Handbrake? ffmpeg?

Nonetheless, the filesize is determined by your resolution, framerate and bitrate. Try exporting the video with VBR with 2 passes and set the bitrate to something between 3 and 6 - that should be enough for a 1920x1080 h264.

Comment: *3 to 6 kbps.  And I'd emphasize that framerate matters here, so more towards 6 kbps for 30 fps.

Comment: How do I find what media encoder I'm using?

Comment: @ClassicNoob I mean the program you use for the encoding. Which software are you putting these settings in?

Comment: I'm guessing you'r asking what software I'm using. As I mentioned in my first post I'm using VSDC. Here is a link to their website http://www.videosoftdev.com/